# Slow Running Query - Will Indexes Help? Not sure what to do with Execution Plan

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, indexing, sql-server-2014

I have this slow running query below that returns 3,023 rows in SQL Server 2014 in a full minute and a half.  Is there anything I can do to speed it up?

I have indexes on all the fields it's joining on.  ArticleAuthor has 99 million rows and #ArticleAuthorTemp gets filled very quickly beforehand with all the IDs I need from ArticleAuthor (3,023 rows) with 0% cost of execution plan. I filled the temp table only for that purpose to limit what it's doing in the query you see here.

The execution plan for the query below is saying it's spending the most time on 2 key lookups and an index seek, each of these things at about 30%.  I'm not sure how to create the needed indexes from these or if that would even help?  Kind of new to index stuff. I hate to just throw indexes on everything.  Even without the 2 LEFT JOINS or outer query, it's very slow so I'm thinking the real issue is with ArticleAuthor table. You'll see the indexes I have on this table below too... :)

I can provide any info you need on the execution plan if that helps.

```
SELECT tot.*,pu.LastName+', '+ ISNULL(pu.FirstName,'') CreatedByPerson,COALESCE(pf.updateddate,pf.CreatedDate) CreatedDatePerson 
from (      
    SELECT  CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), AA.Id) ArticleId
            , 0 Citations
            , AA.FullName
            , AA.LastName
            , AA.FirstInitial
            , AA.FirstName GivenName
            , AA.Affiliations
    FROM ArticleAuthor AA WITH (NOLOCK) 
    INNER JOIN #ArticleAuthorTemp AAT ON AAT.Id = AA.Id
)tot LEFT JOIN AcademicAnalytics..pub_articlefaculty pf WITH (NOLOCK) ON tot.ArticleId = pf.SourceId
    LEFT JOIN AAPortal..portal_user pu on pu.id = COALESCE(pf.updatedby,pf.CreatedBy)
```

Indexes:

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Name] ON [dbo].[ArticleAuthor]
(
[LastName] ASC,
[FirstName] ASC,
[FirstInitial] ASC
)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ID] ON [dbo].[ArticleAuthor]
(
[Id] ASC
)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ArticleID] ON [dbo].[ArticleAuthor]
    (
[ArticleId] ASC
    )
```

Comment: The first thing you should do is get rid of those NOLOCK hints. They are NOT a performance enhancement tool. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/ You should also specify the schema on your objects. It isn't much benefit but the engine has to lookup the default schema for the user executing the query. Can you post that actual execution plan here?

Comment: I would comment out each join and references from outermost to inner most until you hit a bottleneck and then focus on the indexes for the entities in that relationship.

Comment: After running only the innermost query and NOLOCK, it took over a full minute still.  94% of the query execution plan is on a key lookup. I can't seem to add image in comment here, but it's telling me it's on: OBJECT: ArticleAuthor.IX_Name and OUTPUT LIST: ArticleAuthor.FullName and ArticleAuthor.Affiliations.

Comment: Are the index statistics up to date? See [Update Statistics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187348.aspx).

Comment: @HABO yes, and the indexes are all defragmented.

Comment: The percentages in the plans are estimates and can be totally wrong. Look at `statistics io` output to see what table causes most logical reads.

Comment: A screenshot of the execution plan is nothing like the actual file. There is a huge wealth of information in the execution plan to help with a better indexing strategy. Here is an awesome series of articles about indexing. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/72399/

Comment: The derived table `tot` is unnecessary. Don't know if hurts your execution plan, but it very well might. Just straight up join all those tables and start with `#ArticleAuthorTemp` at the very top.

Comment: Multiple problems with this query - the calculated ArticleID , the COALESCE statement and using a temporary table that most likely *doesn't* have any indexes, means there will be a lot of table scans. I bet that if you ditches the temporary table you'd get *better* performance. The same, if you *replaced* that coalesce statement with a UNION of two separate queries or a simple logical statement

Comment: *Why* are you converting the ArticleAuthor.ID? This is enough to invalidate any indexes. Make sure the temporary table's ID column has the same type *and* an index, and join on that.

Comment: I am converting the ArticleAuthor.ID because unfortunately it's an INT field here and a VARCHAR on the other tables.  I didn't make these tables! :)  I will try converting on the temp table first and adding an index to it.  Filling the temp table seems to be very quick in less than 0 seconds, however.  I'll try joining with #ArticleAuthorTemp at the top too.  Thanks for updates, guys...I'll test this out here soon.  Sorry, there's a lot going on with this crazy query!

Comment: 99 million rows with clustered index on three _varchar_ columns (with an additional rid value for uniqueness)?..

Answer (score 0):

Google the CREATE INDEX statement and learn about the INCLUDES part.   Use INCLUDES to eliminate Key Lookups by including all the columns that your query needs to return.

Comment: Thanks @TabAlleman.  I will try this too.  Does this hurt other queries that might run against the table that don't need all those extra columns in the INCLUDES?  Indexing is a somewhat mystery to me, still learning. ;)

Comment: No, adding INCLUDES will not affect other SELECT queries that don't need the included columns.